# Let $X$ be a Banach space and $M\subseteq X$ be a linear manifold (= a vector subspace). Show that $^{\perp}(M^{\perp})=\overline{M}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, orthogonality

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $M\subseteq X$ be a linear manifold (= a vector subspace). Show that $^{\perp}(M^{\perp})=\overline{M}$.

I have seen proofs for this when $X$ is a Hilbert space but I have not seen one for Banach spaces. I am using Conway's Functional Analysis, here:
\begin{align*}
M^{\perp}=\{g\in X^*:\,g(M)=0\}.
\end{align*}
Now in general, the norm on a Banach space is not induced by an inner product so how do we even write $^{\perp}(M^{\perp})$ as a set like $M^{\perp}$ above? Or is that the whole point of the problem? And I have never seen this notation before, is $^{\perp}(M^{\perp})=(M^{\perp})^{\perp}$? I would love to see a detailed proof here because I feel quite confused but any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For $N \subseteq X^{\ast}$ we have ${}^{\perp}N = \{ x \in X : f \in N \implies f(x) = 0\} = \bigcap_{f \in N} \ker f$, whereas $N^{\perp}$ would be a subspace of $X^{\ast\ast}$. The proof is an application of Hahn-Banach.

Comment: For starters,  $ {}^\perp (M^\perp) $ is almost-surely meant to be $ (M^\perp)^\perp $.  And there is no difficulty in applying the definition again: $ (M^\perp)^\perp = \{ h \in X^{\*\*} : h(M^\perp) = 0 \} $.  Are you familiar, from your studies, with the identification of $ X $ with a subset of $ X^{\*\*} $, via the embedding $ X \ni x \mapsto \xi \in X^{\*\*} $ where $ \xi(g) = g(x) $, making $ \xi $ a member of $ X^{\*\*} $?

Edit - reading the above comment, I see it's possible that the notation $ {}^\perp(M) $ might be meant to denote a compliment in $ X $ rather than $ X^{\*\*} $.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that by ${}^\bot Z$, you denote the pre-annihilator of $Z \subset X^*$, that is,
$$ {}^\bot Z := \{  x \in X \colon \ z^*(x)=0, \ \forall \ z^* \in Z\} \subset X.$$

First, notice that the pre-annihilator of any set $Z \subset X^*$ is closed, since
${}^\bot Z = \bigcap_{z^* \in Z} \ker z^*$. Now, you can easily check that $M \subset {}^\bot (M^\bot) $ and thus
$\overline M \subset {}^\bot (M^\bot) $ [since as mentioned, the pre-annihilator is always a closed set]. Now you can use Hahn-Banach to show that the two sets are actually equal.